# How to pass in object definition body to a function

Tags: html, scala, scalate, scuery

My goal is to DRY up the repetitive parts of the definition of objects passed to a generic function in the following block of code:

```
renderTpl(response, "person.html", new Transformer {
  $(".person :first-child").contents = name
  $(".person :last-child").contents = age
})
```

I would like to DRY out the `new Transformer` part and be able to pass the block in the 2nd argument list of `renderTpl` instead:

```
renderTpl(response, "person.html") {
  $(".person :first-child").contents = name
  $(".person :last-child").contents = age
}
```

is it possible to achieve this without resorting to macros? I would post my attempts so far but to be honest I couldn't come up with anything right now.

**Background:** I'm using Scalate's awesome [Scuery](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scuery.html) with servlets, combined with Lift's [`net.liftweb.util.Html5`](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.util.Html5%24) and [`org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1) for HTML5 parsing and rendering; the current `renderTpl` and `loadTpl` implementation can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/BRcr9yFz).

Comment: I'm afraid that's simply not possible. The definition of `renderTpl` cannot introduce magically a new scope into its third argument. There was the beginning of an idea here: https://github.com/dsl-paradise/dsl-paradise (scope injection) but it's mostly abandoned.

Comment: @sjrd: yeah, I immediately hit the same thought actually... but Scala enables quite a bit of non-obvious magic so it I thought it premature to simply abandon the idea. Do you think it would be possible with macros though? Just hypothetically — it would be an overkill to use them in most cases like that.

Comment: I believe it's going to be a huge overkill. But you *might* be able to come up with something, although you'd still have to introduce `$` and other things like that in you top-level scope (as a global import), which is going to be a lot less nice than having `new Transformer` here and there.

Comment: I'd have to introduce `$` even when using macros? I thought lexical scoping laws would be transcended by what macros can do. Am I thinking too much in terms of Lisp macros?

Comment: The body of a macro still needs to typecheck before the macro is applied. So no, they cannot transcend the laws of lexical scoping. I don't too much about Lisp, but I suppose Lisp would indeed allow that because it is not statically typed. But Scala is.

Comment: I'd have assumed typechecking is done *after* the AST transformation is applied, but if not, you're clearly right.